# Why does my producer-consumer model implemented by lua coroutine cannot work expectedly？

Tags: lua, coroutine, producer-consumer

I use coroutine to implement a producer-consumer model. My code is as follow:

```lua
function send(prod, x)
    coroutine.resume(prod, x)
end

function receive()
    local x = coroutine.yield()
    return x
end

function consumer()
    return coroutine.create(function ()
        while true do
            local x = receive()
            io.write(x, "\n")
        end
    end)
end

function producer(prod)
    while true do
        local x = io.read()
        send(prod, x)
    end
end

producer(consumer())
```

When I run this code, I got:
[image]

The first input message("Hello World") is gone. It should be printed twice but now only once. In my opinion, the flow chart of my producer-consumer mode should look like this:

[image]

Did I get it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the first string is entered, the functions are called in the following order:

1. `send`,
2. the coroutine returned by `consumer`,
3. `receive`,
4. `producer`.
   Then the program waits for user input.

`local x = coroutine.yield()` and therefore `local x = receive()` yields to `producer`. `io.write(x, "\n")` is not reached at this stage.

After user inputs a second line, it goes as follows:

1. `send`,
2. `consumer` is resumed after `local x = receive()` and prints the second input,
3. in its endless loop, `consumer` calls `receive`,
4. `receive` yields to `producer`,
5. which waits for user input.

Here is more correct code:

```lua
local function send (x)
    coroutine.yield(x)
end

local function receive (prod)
    local status, value = coroutine.resume(prod)
    return value
end

local function producer()
    return coroutine.create(
        function ()
            while true do
                local x = io.read()     -- produce new value
                send(x)
            end
        end
    )
end

function consumer (prod)
    while true do
        local x = receive(prod)   -- get new value
        io.write(x, "\n")          -- consume new value
    end
end
    
consumer(producer())
```

Note, that it's `consumer(producer())`, not other way round. Also note that `producer` is the coroutine, not `consumer`. Also `send` yields and `receive` resumes.

`consumer` begins the programme, resuming `producer` again and again. If it is other way round, as in your example, `consumer` is not ready to consume the product until the second iteration.

**UPD:** Here follows the "force-feeding", i.e., producer-driven, code:

```lua
local function send (cons, x)
    coroutine.resume (cons, x)
end

local function receive ()
    return coroutine.yield()
end

local function consumer()
    return coroutine.create (
        function (x)
            while true do
                io.write(x, '\n')
                -- corotine.yield() returns the extra arguments of coroutine.resume()
                x = receive()
            end
        end
    )
end

function producer (cons)
    while true do
        local x = io.read() -- make a new value
        send (cons, x)      -- feed the new value
    end
end
    
producer (consumer ())
```

The difference from the author's example is that the `producer` `send`s to the `consumer` and that `receive` goes after `write`.

Further reading: https://www.lua.org/pil/9.2.html.

Comment: Thank you for answering！ But this is not I want. I know this way to implement the producer-consumer model.  In my opinion, the crux of this problem is not whether the procuder is coroutine or not. If the model whose procuder is coroutine and consumer is not can work expectedly, then the opposite way should work expectedly too.

Comment: This problem is an exercise in Programming in Lua Fourth Edition (exercise 24.1 on page 285). It asks me to use producer-driven pattern to implement producer-consumer model. I try to manually resume consumer before the statement `producer(consumer())`. The cod is as follow:  
```lua
--some code  
local co = consumer()  
coroutine.resume(co)  
producer(co)  
```
And it works.

Comment: Thanks you very much！I got it 

Comment: "you can't send more data to coroutine while resuming it" That's just not true.

Comment: That's why it is struck out.

Comment: And deleted altogether now, to prevent further questions.

Answer (score 1):

The first time you "resume" a coroutine, it doesn't jump directly to the first `yield`, but instead calls the wrapped function with the given arguments:

```lua
local co = coroutine.wrap(function(aaa)
   print(aaa) -- prints "first"
   print(coroutine.yield()) -- prints "second"
end)

co("first")
co("second")
```

an easy way to fix this in your code:

```lua
local send, receive =
   coroutine.resume, coroutine.yield

function consumer()
   return coroutine.create(function(x)
      while true do
         io.write(x, "\n")
         x = receive()
      end
   end)
end

function producer(consumer)
   while true do
      local x = io.read()
      send(consumer, x)
   end
end

producer(consumer())
```